# Adding inputs after button click in MVC4 View

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

via http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Is there any possibility to dynamicly add `<input type="file" name="files" id="file[i]" />`
into View (with view model) after clicking button "Add next file", withour reloading page (using jquery)?

Here is main code.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

  <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

  <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

Regards

Comment: why don't you just use multiupload image jquery plugins..instead of creating new file inputs each time ...and letting user upload one file at a time...

Comment: but what if I don't need to use multiupload jquery plugins? :) I just need to upload 5 or 6 or 7 files, that's all.

Comment: then its fine... i was just thinking, what if user have to upload 20 files....that is like.. 20 inputs and upload 20 time.. phewww!!!.. :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery multiple file upload plugin.Take a look  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992874/multiple-file-upload-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery-multiple-file-upload-plugin)

Our you can use jquery

```
$('#Maindiv').append("<label for="file1">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />");
```

set id apt upto your logic.